# Cassandra Row Cache size increased but not receiving row requests

Tags: caching, amazon-ec2, cassandra-2.0

I am using Cassandra 2.2.6 datastax AMI on AWS EC2 instance to analyze row cache perormance. Even after creating a three tables with row caching enabled and increasing row_cache_size, row_cache_keys_to_save and row_cache_save_period. 
Cache memory is populated using Cassandra stress tool using 5M write requests.
I cannot get row cache read requests and row cache hits with read heavy Cassandra-stress test with uniform (1..100000).

nodetool info

```
ID                     : 705c2b22-d049-4ea3-a073-967c3d14cb62
Gossip active          : true
Thrift active          : false
Native Transport active: true
Load                   : 2.74 GB
Generation No          : 1462522631
Uptime (seconds)       : 1543
Heap Memory (MB)       : 936.27 / 1850.00
Off Heap Memory (MB)   : 13.10
Data Center            : us-east
Rack                   : 1a
Exceptions             : 0

Key Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 0 bytes, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds
    Row Cache              : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 1000 MB, 0 hits, 0 

requests, NaN recent hit rate, 14400 save period in seconds

Counter Cache          : entries 0, size 0 bytes, capacity 46 MB, 0 hits, 0 requests, NaN recent hit rate, 7200 save period in seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row cache is populated when data is read from the database. Each time you update that data row cache is being invalidated. Could you explain how did you test this and what were your actual vs desired results?

Comment: I have tested using Cassandra stress tool. I tried populating cache memory by sending 5M write request. Later tried to test row cache performance by sending 5M read requests with UNIFORM(1...100000). I am trying to analyze  row cache performance expecting a better hit rate or result other than zero. Sorry if the question seemed hypothetical and silly.

Comment: This test will not show you what you are looking for. Thats what I tried to explain in my previous answer but its much clearer now. Row cache is populated on first read so when you read the same data again then you read it from cache. With that stress test configuration you are never reading the same data twice.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped me a lot.